# Xpage opens URL with hash

Tags: url, xpages, lotus

I have two Xpages, one containing a repeat control. When clicking on an entry, the second Xpage should open. I am using a link conrol to do this:

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="" id="link1"
value="/Xpage1.xsp?documentId=#{javascript:FA_Row.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">

... complex values to display...

</xp:link>
```

The link opens the following URL:

http://www.serverName.de/path/Xpage1.xsp#/path/Xpage2.xsp?documentID=xxx

When the URL is opend in this way, none of my eventhandlers in XPage2 fire. If I open the document manually, using the following URL, everything works fine.

http://www.serverName.de/path/Xpage2.xsp?documentID=xxx

How do I tell my repeat control to open the URL without the "Xpage1.xsp#"?

---

Here is the complete code of the repeat control, as requested :) It is a categorized view, using jQuery Mobile for formatting.

```
<xp:repeat id="contactRepeat" rows="30"
    value="#{MForApproval}" var="FA_Row" disableOutputTag="true">

<xp:scriptBlock
    rendered="#{javascript:FA_Row.getNoteID()==''}">
    <li data-role="list-divider" data-dividertheme="b">

        ...Category Text...
    </li>
</xp:scriptBlock>

<xp:scriptBlock 
    rendered="#{javascript:FA_Row.getNoteID()!=''}">

    <li>
        <xp:link escape="true" text="LINK" id="link1"
            value="Button_test_1.xsp?documentId=#{javascript:FA_Row.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">

            ...TEXT...

        </xp:link>

    </li>

</xp:scriptBlock>

</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: Seems like your url for the link gets calculated wrong. The XPage1.xsp# will always just reloud your Xpage1. How do you create the url for this link? Could you please add the Code of your repeatControl and your link?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you putting your content inside `<xp:scriptBlock>`? From your code it seems you are using it for hide/when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your version of the  Code and Naveen's. In my example both are working. You could try using a Simple Event or a script event to redirect your User to the other XPage like this:

```
    <xp:link escape="true" text="linkName" id="link2"
        value="">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:openPage name="xpage1.xsp" target="openDocument">
                <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:FA_Row.getDocument().getUniversalID();
}]]></xp:this.documentId>
            </xp:openPage>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:link>
```

Note: if you using the Event double check that the `value=""`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. There seems to be a problem with the jQuery Mobile resources, as soon as I remove them, my links are working, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the URL of the link this way:

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="" id="link1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"/Xpage1.xsp?documentId=" + FA_Row.getDocument().getUniversalID()}]]></xp:this.value>

    ... complex values to display...

</xp:link>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried that, same result as before :(

Comment: This should have worked. Try using this code `../Xpage1.xsp?documentId=#{javascript:FA_Row.getDocument().getUniversalID()}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
<xp:repeat id="contactRepeat" rows="30" 
value="#{MForApproval}" var="FA_Row" disableOutputTag="true">
    <xp:panel tagName="li" rendered="#{javascript:FA_Row.isCategory()}">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="data-role" value="list-divider" />
            <xp:attr name="data-dividertheme" value="b" />
        </xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:text tagName="h3" disableTheme="true" value="#{FA_Row.categoryCol}" />
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:panel tagName="li" rendered="#{javascript:FA_Row.isDocument()}">
        <a href="Xpage1.xsp?documentId=#{javascript:FA_Row.getUniversalID()}">
            <xp:text value="#{FA_Row.ColName}" disableTheme="true" />
        </a>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:repeat>
```

You just need to update column names inside `<xp:text>` tag.